# How can I filter submissions for download?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a query about the webform download options. `/admin/structure/webform/manage/{{webform_name}}/results/download`

In my webform there is a field dropdown with some data like 'a', 'b', 'c'...

Please let me know is it possible to download all submissions whose dropdown value is 'a'?

Comment: You would need to use the Webform Views Integration module (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views ) with View Data Export (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export).